# prove arctan(x) is continuous in $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ is $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous. I know I want to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(y)|< \epsilon$

Unforutnately, I cannot get anywhere from here

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we use properties of integrals, and $\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$?

Comment: **Hint:** Use the following facts : 

(i) $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y = \tan^{-1}\frac{x-y}{1+xy}$

(ii) $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}x \le x$, for $x \ge 0$

(iii) $\tan^{-1}x$ is an increasing odd function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\arctan(x) -\arctan(y) =\arctan( ( x - y)/(1 + xy) ),
$$
hence, for nonnegative $xy$,
$$
|\arctan(x) -\arctan(y)|\leq|\arctan ( x - y)|\leq|x-y|
$$ 
and one can choose $\delta=\varepsilon$. The case $xy<0$ is easy to reduce to the previous one by taking $|x-y|\leq|x-0|+|y-0|$.

Comment: In general, if $|f'(x)| \le a$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| \le a|x-y|$. $|(\arctan(x))'| \le 1$.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks! For the second case, I'm a bit confused as to where $|x-y| \leq |x|+|y|$ helps

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\tan:(-{ \pi \over 2}, {\pi \over 2}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is 
 strictly increasing and surjective.

Since $\tan$ is strictly increasing, it follows that $\arctan$ is also strictly increasing.

Pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $y_1 = (\arctan x)-\epsilon$,
$y_2 = (\arctan x)+\epsilon$, $x_1 = \tan y_1, x_2 = \tan y_2$.

Since $y_1 < \arctan x < y_2$, we have $x_1 < x < x_2$. Let $\delta = \min(x-x_1,x_2-x)$.

Then if $|x'-x| < \delta$, we have $x' \in (x_1, x_2)$ and hence $\arctan x'
\in (y_1,y_2) = ((\arctan x)-\epsilon, (\arctan x)+\epsilon )$ and so
$|\arctan x' - \arctan x| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Why the downvote?