# Continuity and differentiability of a function in two variables.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $L = \{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | ~~ y\leq0\}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus L \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) , ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\mbox{if } x>0, \\ \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x} \right) + \pi, ~~~~~~~\mbox{if } x<0, \\ \frac{\pi}{2}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\mbox{if } x=0, y>0.\end{cases}$$
How to show that $f$ is continuous? Is $f$ differentiable? If so, what is its derivative?

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable on $L'$ or on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus L$?  Note that arctan is 1-Lipschitz: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1008532/290189

Comment: @ GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 On $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus L$

Comment: Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Okay I thought of writing how this function originate but then on second thought it will be too long so i just keep the part that i want

Comment: Please edit your question to show your thoughts.  The case for $x \ne 0$ should be easy: treat $f$ as a composition of two functions.  The inner one should be easy, and the outer one is differentiable : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1171975/290189

Comment: what do you mean by inner one

Comment: $(x,y) \mapsto y/x$

Comment: Yes I know that for $x\neq 0$ the function will be continuous, the difficult case is when $x=0$. How do I approach in proving the continuity of these kinds of functions

Comment: I suggest borrowing the technique of writing inverse function in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/294695/290189.

Comment: Refer to Rudin 9.24: *$f$ is a continuously differentiable map if and only if $f$ has continuous partial derivatives*. Can you calculate the partial derivatives of $f$?